# r.sun delievering unrealistic Values

Tags: grass-gis

I need your help. I'm trying to calculate the global irridiation for a specific area. I'm interested in the results for rooftops in special. 
I have a DEM, calculated slope, aspect and horizons and started `r.sun` for every day with a monthly changing Linke Factor. All calculated maps (slope, aspect, horizons) seem to have believable values. 
My Problem is: On the yearly sum (addition of all 365 days) I get values for total global irridiation of about 1900 KW/m². Which is 1,9times more then expected. Especially when the solar constant is only 1368 kW/m²....
Could you imagine what went wrong? I'm lost.

Comment: Why are you summing all of 365 days? it doesn't have sense... the global year irradiation, it's the average of all the 654 days not the sum.

Comment: sorry, i wanted to calculate the sum of KWh/m² so, as glob_rad gives the Wh/m² per day i sum them up (and divide them by 1000)

Comment: is it neccesary to give input for coef_bh and coef_bf?

Comment: No it's not neccessary. Can you paste here the code of one day and the code that you use for calculating the sum?

Comment: Code for each day: r.sun --verbose elev_in=SLEfpgespatch@Mapset882014 asp_in=SLEfpgespatchexposition@Mapset882014 slope_in=SLEfpgespatchneigung@Mapset882014 lin=3.3 lat_in=latslefpgespatch@Mapset882014 long_in=longslefpgespatch@Mapset882014 horizon=horizontslegespatch horizon_step=5 glob_rad=Gesamt365 day=365 num_partitions=10

Comment: code for month (April): result = Gesamt91@Mapset882014 + Gesamt92@Mapset882014 +... Gesamt120@Mapset88201

Comment: code for year: result = JanSumme + FebSumme + MaeSumme + AprSumme + MaiSumme +         |
 |    JunSumme + JulSumme + AugSumme + SepSumme + OktSumme + NovSumme +       |
 |    DezSumme

Comment: as it seems my resultng pixels with nearly 0degrees slope and now shadoweffects have a yearly calculated sum of ~1630 KWh/m²/a wich is quiet close to the sums of "Monthly Averaged Clear Sky Insolation Incident On A Horizontal Surface (kWh/m2/day)" i got from here: https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/subset.cgi?email=skip%40larc.nasa.gov . So i´m wondering if anything went wrong in r.sun, like the realsky/clearsky calculation needed parameters as input or didnt calculate accurately....Thanks a lot for your efforts!!!

Comment: I noticed you wanted to delete this question because you've found an answer. Instead of deleting, please consider adding the answer you've found as an answer here, and mark it as accepted, so that people with a similar issue in the future might find your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I just found the answer fo myself, reading the manual carefully and focused.
The r.sun mode 2 computes just the clear-sky irridiation. To get the "real-sky" irridiation you have to multiply the result with a clearsky Factor (Kc). Kc is defined as the ratio of messured Irridation on Ground under overcast situation and the clearsky amount messured via satellite (both for horizontal orientatian) and has values from 0-1.0 . Data to calculate the Kc-Factor can be requested here: https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/subset.cgi?email=skip@larc.nasa.gov
After multiplying the results with Kc the results seem to be realistic.

Thanks all for trying to help!!!