# How to determine Kc value and apply it to r.sun?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, grass-7.0, qgis-grass-plugin

As outlined in this link ( [r.sun delievering unrealistic Values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112467/r-sun-delievering-unrealistic-values) ) to get realistic values of kilowatt / meter-2, you must multiply the results by a "clear sky factor (Kc)". The link comments recommend this website, https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/subset.cgi?email=skip@larc.nasa.gov, but there is no option to determining Kc. I have tried to follow the directions on determining the ratio of overcast situation to clear sky but neither are options on the NASA page. Also, I don't know how to multiply the output raster by whatever the Kc value might be. Can anyone assist?

**From the original answer:**

> The r.sun mode 2 computes just the clear-sky irridiation. To get the
>   "real-sky" irridiation you have to multiply the result with a clearsky
>   Factor (Kc). Kc is defined as the ratio of messured Irridation on
>   Ground under overcast situation and the clearsky amount messured via
>   satellite (both for horizontal orientatian) and has values from 0-1.0
>   . Data to calculate the Kc-Factor can be requested here:
>   https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/subset.cgi?email=skip@larc.nasa.gov
>   After multiplying the results with Kc the results seem to be
>   realistic.

Comment: Take a look [into this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X10000812?via%3Dihub)